# Change runtime research for a compile time one

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-hana

*I'm trying to implement a generic ECS library in C++ for learning purpose. I was thinking about a lot of way to implement things but I always run into a problem. So if you could help me with this one :*

Let say I have a `constexpr hana::tuple` of `hana::type_c` Components, something like :

```
struct C1 {};
struct C2 {};
struct C3 {};

constexpr auto components = hana::to_tuple(hana::tuple_t<C1, C2, C3>);
```

And now I have a component storage type, which is not a problem here, so let's call it Storage (the type differ for each component):

```
struct Storage {};
```

I want to link each component or each component group, with their `Storage` type. So the easy way is to do something like that:

```
constexpr auto component_storage = hana::make_tuple(
hana::make_pair(hana::to_tuple(hana::tuple_t<C1, C2>), type_c<Storage>),
hana::make_pair(hana::to_tuple(hana::tuple_t<C3>), type_c<Storage>)
);
```

But the problem now is runtime. If I initialize that tuple but with the real Storage and no longer `type_c<Storage>`, I'll have to loop through the tuple to find the `Storage` that I need. All of this at runtime no?
And this is really bad, my last version had something like `Component::getStorage()` and it was free (but more restrictive).

So the question is : **how can I manage to have some `getStorage<Component>()` function which will cost nothing at runtime?** Well by nothing I mean just return the reference of the Storage.

EDIT: The only way I have think so far is quite simple (sounds like a good point).

*Pseudo-Code*

```
struct LinkedStorage {

  hana::tuple<...>            storages;
  hana::tuple<hana::pair...>  index;
};
```

At lest something like:

```
constexpr auto components = hana::to_tuple(hana::tuple_t<C1, C2, C3>);
constexpr auto storage = hana::to_tuple(hana::tuple_t<Storage, Storage>);
constexpr auto index = hana::make_tuple(
hana::make_pair(hana::to_tuple(hana::tuple_t<C1>, 0),
hana::make_pair(hana::to_tuple(hana::tuple_t<C2, C3>, 1)
);
```

Like that I should be able to found the index at compile time and just access the right element at runtime. But I'm new at metaprogramming, so I guess someone could make something far better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, no need to use `to_tuple(tuple_t<...>)`; you can just use `tuple_t<...>`. Now, I think what you actually want to do (since you seem to need runtime storage, which makes sense) is:

```
// "map" of a set of types to a storage of some type
using StorageMap = hana::tuple<
  hana::pair<hana::tuple<hana::type<C1>, hana::type<C2>>, StorageA>,
  hana::pair<hana::tuple<hana::type<C3>>, StorageB>
>;
// Actual object that contains the runtime storage (and the free mapping between types)
StorageMap map;
```

Now, you can implement your `getStorage<Component>()` function like this:

```
template <typename Component>
decltype(auto) getStorage() {
  auto found = index_if(map, [](auto const& pair) {
    return hana::contains(hana::first(pair), hana::type<Component>{});
  });
  return hana::second(hana::at(map, found));
}
```

where `index_if` is a trivial variant of the function presented [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33987589/627587) that would work on an arbitrary predicate instead of a specific element. This functionality will be added to Hana when I get some free time (see [related ticket](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/issues/273)).

Comment: Big thanks for your help, but does this mean that `getStorage` will be reduce to `return hana::second(index)` ? You don't even need a `constexpr` keyword with the found variable? Seems like I have to learn a lot of meta programming stuff.

Comment: The `found` variable is an `integral_constant` that contains the value of the index in its type. So no, no need for `constexpr`.

Comment: should it not be `return hana::second(hana::at(map, found.value()));`? as found is a `hana::optional`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to make a map that can look up a single instance using different keys. Here is a snippet from an old implementation that I wrote. I modified it a bit, but it should convey the idea.

```
namespace detail {
    // extractKeys - returns pairs of each element and itself
    struct extract_keys_fn
    {
        template<typename TypesType>
        constexpr auto operator()(TypesType s) const {
            return decltype(hana::unpack(typename TypesType::type{},
                hana::make_tuple
                ^hana::on^
                hana::reverse_partial(hana::make_pair, s)
            )){};
        }
    };
    constexpr extract_keys_fn extract_keys{};
}//detail

template<typename ...Pair>
struct multi_map
{
    // the keys must be `type<tuple<path...>>`
    using Storage = decltype(hana::make_map(std::declval<Pair>()...));

    // each key is a hana::tuple which contain the keys we
    // want to use to lookup an element
    using Lookup = decltype(hana::unpack(
        hana::flatten(hana::unpack(hana::keys(std::declval<Storage>()),
            hana::make_tuple ^hana::on^ detail::extract_keys)),
        hana::make_map
    ));

    constexpr multi_map()
        : storage()
    { }

    constexpr multi_map(Pair&&... p)
        : storage(hana::make_map(std::forward<Pair>(p)...))
    { }

    constexpr multi_map(Pair const&... p)
        : storage(hana::make_map(p...))
    { }

    constexpr multi_map(Pair&... p)
        : storage(hana::make_map(p...))
    { }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator[](T t) const&
    {
        return hana::at_key(storage, hana::at_key(Lookup{}, t));
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator[](T t) &
    {
        return hana::at_key(storage, hana::at_key(Lookup{}, t));
    }

    template<typename T>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator[](T t) &&
    {
        return hana::at_key(storage, hana::at_key(Lookup{}, t));
    }

    Storage storage;
};
```

The basics of what is happening above is that `storage` is a `hana::map` containing the instances that you need references to. Then `Lookup` is a `hana::map` that points each key to the key that is used in `storage` (which is a tuple of all the keys that point to it). It's basically just a map to map, but with it you can get a reference to a single instance using any one of the keys.

Comment: Seems like I have to get some experience before to be able to understand this code sorry. I'll keep it in mind and come back later, thanks :)

Comment: I added a bit of a description. Lambdas would help the readability a lot, but they aren't allowed in constexpr (before c++1z) or inside decltype.

Comment: Sorry, there is one thing that I couldn't find anywhere : `^hana::on^`. By the way I don't have any c++ limitations (using c++1z and concept TS for now).

Comment: Think `[](auto ...args) { return make_tuple(extract_keys(args)...); }`. If you can use constexpr lamdas then do that. The `^` is hana's infix operator.