# boost hana index_if and type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

I wonder why, in this code, the type of `i` is an empty optional.

```
auto t = boost::hana::make_tuple(boost::hana::type_c<int>, boost::hana::type_c<double>);
auto i = boost::hana::index_if(t, boost::hana::is_a<boost::hana::type<double>>);
```

To me, it should be `optional<hana::size_t<1>>`

I know there is [Boost hana get index of first matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979592/boost-hana-get-index-of-first-matching) but it is not exactly the same question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`boost::hana::is_a` returns whether the **tag** of an object matches a given tag. [[reference]](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-core.html#ga38cf78e1e3e262f7f1c71ddd9ca70cd9)

You're not passing it a tag, you're passing it a `hana::type` instead.

For example, you could test whether the argument is a `hana::type`, and `i` would contain a `size_c<0>` (because the first item in the tuple is already a `hana::type`):

```
auto i = hana::index_if(t, hana::is_a<hana::type_tag>);
```

---

If you want to check for equality to some type, use `equal::to`:

```
auto i = hana::index_if(t, hana::equal.to(hana::type_c<double>));
```

[[Reference to hana::equal]](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Comparable.html#gacaf1ebea6b3ab96ac9dcb82f0e64e547)

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/hH-POt)